# Draw Triangle iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

The code below is drawing me a circle, how can I modify the existing code to draw a triangle instead?

```
    _colorDotLayer = [CALayer layer];

    CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width-6;
    _colorDotLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width);
    _colorDotLayer.allowsGroupOpacity = YES;
    _colorDotLayer.backgroundColor = self.annotationColor.CGColor;
    _colorDotLayer.cornerRadius = width/2;
    _colorDotLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
```

Comment: This approach isn't useful for drawing a triangle. You should look into UIBezierPath to do that.

Comment: You should also look into CGContext.

Comment: SO isn't a code translation service.

Answer (score 17):

While there are shown several Core Graphics solution, I want to add a Core Animation based solution.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, view3.frame.size.height-100)];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view3.frame.size.width/2,100)];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view3.frame.size.width, view2.frame.size.height)];
    [trianglePath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.75 alpha:1];
    view.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

code based on my blog post.

Comment: This webpage is not available

Comment: It doesn't work if the view needs to be resized to fit the screen, which is very common (because it comes out of the storyboard at whatever size you used in the storyboard). You need to set the path during the layout phase (as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25578729/77567)), or use a `drawRect:`-based solution like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25578212/77567) with a content mode of redraw or scale-to-fit.

Answer (score 11):

```
@implementation TriangleView {
    CAShapeLayer *_colorDotLayer;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (_colorDotLayer == nil) {
        _colorDotLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        _colorDotLayer.fillColor = self.annotationColor.CGColor;
        [self.layer addSublayer:_colorDotLayer];
    }

    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGFloat radius = (bounds.size.width - 6) / 2;
    CGFloat a = radius * sqrt((CGFloat)3.0) / 2;
    CGFloat b = radius / 2;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, -radius)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(a, b)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-a, b)];
    [path closePath];
    [path applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds))];
    _colorDotLayer.path = path.CGPath;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.annotationColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

Result:

[image: triangle view]

Answer (score 4):

I think is more easy than this solutions:

```
 UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
[path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){20, 0}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){40, 40}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 40}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){20, 0}];

// Create a CAShapeLayer with this triangular path
// Same size as the original imageView
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
mask.frame = self.viewTriangleCallout.bounds;
mask.path = path.CGPath;
```

[image]

This is my white triangle:
You can change points or rotate if you want:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
[path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 0}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){40, 0}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){20, 20}];
[path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 0}];

// Create a CAShapeLayer with this triangular path
// Same size as the original imageView
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
mask.frame = self.viewTriangleCallout.bounds;
mask.path = path.CGPath;
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use closePath instead of the last addLineToPoint.

Answer (score 3):

Example code, it is based on this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8446655/451475) which draws stars:

```
@implementation TriangleView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    int sides = 3;
    double size = 100.0;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(160.0, 100.0);

    double radius = size / 2.0;
    double theta = 2.0 * M_PI / sides;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y-radius);
    for (NSUInteger k=1; k<sides; k++) {
        float x = radius * sin(k * theta);
        float y = radius * cos(k * theta);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x+x, center.y-y);
    }
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextFillPath(context);           // Choose for a filled triangle
    // CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2); // Choose for a unfilled triangle
    // CGContextStrokePath(context);      // Choose for a unfilled triangle
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use UIBezeierPaths

```
CGFloat radius = 20;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, (center.x + bottomLeft.x) / 2, (center.y + bottomLeft.y) / 2);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, center.x, center.y, radius);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, radius);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Comment: This is not executable code. What is 'center'? What is 'bottomLeft'?