# Render play image over existing image in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avassetimagegenerator

I have collection view with some videos and images

Using AVFoundation able to capture video from iPhone and generated thumbnail using AVAssetImageGenerator. When shown in gallery image should distinguish it's of video thumbnail. So i need to transform exact image by drawing video symbol(like play icon) over it.

Is it possible?

Comment: What other tools/libraries are you using besides Objective C? It's hard to give an answer without you being more precise about your problem. (otherwise I might as well suggest print the images out on transparent paper and lay them on top of each other...)

Comment: Using AVFoundation able to capture video from iPhone and generated thumbnail using AVAssetImageGenerator. When shown in gallery image should distinguish it's of video thumbnail. So i need to transform exact image by drawing video symbol(like play icon) over it.

Comment: Please add this information to your question and tag your question with the appropriate tags. People might not have time to read all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CoreGraphics` to edit the image.

First, create a `UIImage` with the image you would like to edit.  Then, do something like this:

```
UIImage *oldThumbnail; //set this to the original thumbnail image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(oldThumbnail.size);
[oldThumbnail drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, oldThumbnail.size.width, oldThumbnail.size.height)];

/*Now there are two ways to draw the play symbol.

One would be to have a pre-rendered play symbol that you load into a UIImage and draw with drawInRect */

UIImage *playSymbol = [UIImage imageNamed:"PlaySymbol.png"];
CGRect playSymbolRect; //I'll let you figure out calculating where you should draw the play symbol
[playSymbol drawInRect: playSymbolRect];

//The other way would be to draw the play symbol directly using CoreGraphics calls.  Start with this:
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

`//now use CoreGraphics calls.  I won't go over it here, but`[`the second answer to this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578090/draw-triangle-ios)`may be helpful.`

```
//Once you have finished drawing your image, you can put it in a UIImage.
UIImage *newThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); //make sure you remember to do this :)
```

Now you can use the newly generated thumbnail in a UIImageView, cache it so you don't need to re-render it every time, etc.

Comment: What should be the playSymbolRect coordinates? I

Comment: That is for you to calculate based on geometry and your image coordinates.  You can use the `size` property of `UIImage`s.  For example, `playSymbol.size.width` or `playSymbol.size.height`.  If you want to put the play button in the center, you could either just hardcode the values (if you plan to always use the same size images) or calculate it based off of the sizes of the images involved.

Comment: Also this may help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work (you may have to play with positions and sizes):

```
-(UIImage*)drawPlayButton:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIImage *playButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [playButton drawInRect:CGRectMake(image.size.width/2-playButton.size.width/2, image.size.height/2-playButton.size.height/2, playButton.size.width, playButton.size.height)];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```